# How to work with spring4+spring-data-jpa(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter)+multidatasource+one entityManager+jpaRepository?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I  come across a project that has two database but data structure in these database are different, involved in transaction management in multidatasource.

Beside, I would like to use `JpaRepository`, which just add `@Repository` annotation to some Interface extending `JpaRepository`, focusing me on sql sentence. For example:

```
@Scope(value="prototype")
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>,
 JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
    @Query(value="select * from users",nativeQuery=true)
    public List<User>  getAll();

    @Query(value="select * from users where email=binary ?1 or   phone_number=?1",nativeQuery=true)
    public User findUserByEmailOrPhone(String name);

    public User save(User user);

    @Modifying
    @Query("Update User u set u.lastLoginTime=?2,u.mac=?3,u.lastIp=?4 where u.id=?1")
    public int updateLast_login(Integer id,Date last_loginTime,String mac,
          String last_ip);
  }
```

Regarding to transaction management, I would like to keep use of `@Transctional` annotation but it involves the execution of sql sentence in two mysql database.

I guess there is only one `entityManagerFactory` to manage different entity class in two datasource, according to my experience of one datasource.

But how to configue the map of  `JpaRepository` interface and  datasource and tell the `entityManagerFactory` the map of datasource and entity class?

Here is example of my function I want to accomplish mentioned above.

```
// this entity data  is restored in A databse's Atab table
@Table
@Entity
public class A{
   private String A_item1;
   private Integer A_item2;
   private Long A_item3;
   public A(){
      super();
   }
}
 // this entity data is restored in B databse's Btab table
 @Table
 @Entity
 public class B{
     private String B_item1;
     private Integer B_item2;
     private Long B_item3;
     public B(){
         super();
     }
 }

 @Repository
 public interface A_Repository extends JpaRepository<A, Integer>,
 JpaSpecificationExecutor<A>{

      public A save(A a);

      @Modifying
      @Query(value="update Atab  set a_item1=?1 where a_item2=?2",nativeQuery=true)
      public A update(String a_item1,int a_item2 );

      public A update(A a);
 }

 @Repository
 public interface B_Repository extends JpaRepository<B, Integer>,
 JpaSpecificationExecutor<B>{

      public B save(B a);

      @Modifying
      @Query(value="update Btab  set b_item1=?1 where b_item2=?2",nativeQuery=true)
      public B update(String b_item1,int b_item2 );

      public B update(B b);
 }

 @service
 public class A_B_Service{

    @Autowired
    A_Repository a_Repos;

    @Autowired
    B_Repository b_Repos;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void synchronous_save_AandB(A a,B b){
          a_Repos.save(a);
          b_Repos.save(b);

    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void synchronous_update_AandB(A a,B b){
          a_Repos.update(a);
          b_Repos.update(b);
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void synchronous_update_AandB(String a_item1,int a_item2,String b_item1,int b_item2){
          a_Repos.update( a_item1,a_item2);
          b_Repos.update(b_item1,b_item2);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless each DB is essentially self-contained.

Each entity belongs to one or more `JPARepository` (yes, you can have multiple repositories for each entity if you want).

Each `JPARepository` belongs to one `EntityManager` (if using Hibernate and Spring, it's based upon your scanning package)  You may have multiple `EntityManager`s scan the same package, but I would think you'd have concurrency and data overwriting issues if you do.

Each `EntityManager` only has one datasource.  (there are no multi datasource `EntityManager`s I'm aware of)

Each transaction may have multiple `EntityManager`s.  It can't be your standard `@Transactional`, you'll have to configure a `JTATransactionalManager` in place of the standard one, but that shouldn't be too hard.  Note that you can have at most 1 non-XA datasource in each transaction.

Note also that SQL or JPQL across datasources/`EntityManager`s are not supported by any `EntityManager` I am aware of.

Comment: ,thank you!according your comment,I have search some matterisals about `JTATransactionalManager`,but it is not   integrated about configure and usage.My webservice machine is tomcat7,do I need to find a new webservice container?I am new to `JTATransactionalManager`,can you find some example or matterial about my circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some additional configuration options to accomplish this

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  basePackages = { "com.yourappliction.feature1.repositories" },
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFeature1",
  transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerFeature1"
)

@EnableJpaRepositories(
  basePackages = { "com.yourapplication.feature2.repositories" },
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryFeature2",
  transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerFeature2"
)
```

What this means is you need to configure 2 beans both for`EntityManagerFactory` and `TransactionManager`.

Your `JpaRepository` interfaces inside *feature1* would then use those specific beans while *feature2* would use the other configured beans.

There is no way to accomplish this with a single `EntityManagerFactory` because a factory is specifically dedicated to a datasource.  There are some custom frameworks that have been developed in the past to support this but it isn't a native feature to JPA.